# How to select common parameters from two interfaces in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

**Select must be not only by key name but by types of these params**

For example:

```js
    interface human {
      name: string,
      height: number,
      weight:number
    }

    interface robot {
      name: number,
      height: number,
      weight:number
    }
```

***Result must be***:

```js
    interface commonHumanRobot{
      height: number,
      weight: number
    }
```

There is a solution based on the answer of @Acid Coder

```js
type selectCommon<T extends object, B extends object> = {
  [key in keyof T as T[key] extends B[key&keyof B]? B[key&keyof B] extends T[key]? key:never:never]:T[key]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
interface human {
    name: string,
    height: number,
    weight: number
}

interface robot {
    name: number,
    height: number,
    weight: number
}

type SelectCommon<T, V> =
    { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends V[K & keyof V] ? V[K & keyof V] extends T[K] ? T[K] : never : never }

type RemoveNeverType<T> = { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends never ? never : K]: T[K] }

type A = RemoveNeverType<SelectCommon<human, robot>>
//   ^?
```

[image]

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=8&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBYFcC2cTIN4BQyxyIcmEAXMgM5hSgDmANESahMI6mNSFgCNorEsgDunbr1KDoBAL4ECoSLEQooAewGaw+NsTIU+sqCPaSeJzELMHxl6fxtzFBMAE8ADigDKEABsIBDAAYU1MTE0QAB4AFWZkADUAPmQAXns8ZABtAGlkUGQAawgPTRhkOIBdajj86uQIAA9IEAATGmT85AAyErKK5MaAfm6C-tLyyqTGlrbOqobkMfq8xr4IADdoZE2dqGQ3Tx9kACUIKJ2AOW3oOO8IeLT0-FyCoqmhuOQ4LrW5q0IB0uiA7ocxmCDntkOs6stjo9kABBDLnS6aG7gh4+GL+IIhcKRaIxDDYECJLQ6MApFIEAD09JIAD0RkA)

update: shorter using intersection `&`

```
interface human {
    name: string,
    height: number,
    weight: number,
    a: 1
}

interface robot {
    name: number,
    height: number,
    weight: number
}

type SelectCommon<T, V> =
    { [K in keyof T & keyof V as (T & V)[K] extends never ? never : K]: (T & V)[K] }

type A = SelectCommon<human, robot>
//   ^?
```

[image]
[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBYFcC2cTIN4BQyxyIcmEAXMgM5hSgDmANESahMI6mNSFgCNorEsgDunbr1KDhbYnGoBGAgF8CBUJFiIUUAPYD9YfPNLkqMzEKgj2knn1m2zEro6s21GsAE8ADigAyhAANhAIYADC+piY+iAAPAAqzMgAagB8yAC8ZnjIANoA0sigyADWEL76MMjJyABkldW1GchwNMgAFA3N6QCUJQC6yBAAHpAgACZdIBAAbtDIAPyki8vUxcPUvU0ZQ9vI6gR+gcgAgrnIIeGRMXEJiRjYIGkGRmCZBAD0PyQAPRWBCAA)

however this come with less safe type eg `1 & number` is `1`, in my longer example, this will result in `never` which I think is safer but I guess `1 & number` is `1` does not have any risk, so it makes sense too

Comment: @Андрей I fixed a small bug in my short solution, please check it again

Comment: I created a solution based on yours and add it in the end of my question, can you check it is it right way of things?

Comment: @Андрей test fail against `{a: number, b: number}` and `{a: number, c: number}`, because you did not check the type of key of B, you check only the type of value

Comment: I Added minor change, couple minutes ago

Comment: @Андрей that seem to be working, I think it is ok

Comment: I see, that is a shorter version of my long solution

Comment: Yep, I mentioned that its based on your solution.

Comment: that is a smart modification, but I think you can use the other one, it is more elegant and safe enough

Comment: I think that these type vulnerability in context of 1 and number types is quite a bit damaging my perfectionism. But yep, its much more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

```
type NonNeverKeys<Type1, Type2, Inter = Type1 & Type2> = {
    [Key in keyof Inter]: Inter[Key] extends never ? never : Key
}[keyof Inter];
type NonNeverIntersect<Type1, Type2> = Pick<Type1 & Type2, NonNeverKeys<Type1, Type2>>;

interface human {
  name: string,
  height: number,
  weight: number
}

interface robot {
  name: number,
  height: number,
  weight: number
}

const inter: NonNeverIntersect<human, robot>;
```